# Why is static_assert breaking substitution?

Tags: c++, sfinae, static-assert

Please, consider the following C++14 code:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
class Bar {
    static_assert(std::is_destructible<T>::value, "T must be destructible");
};

template<typename T>
void foo(Bar<T> const &) {}

template<typename T>
void foo(T const &) {}

class Product {
public:
    static Product *createProduct() { return new Product{}; }
    static void destroyProduct(Product *product) { delete product; }
private:
    Product() = default;
    ~Product() = default;
};

int main()
{
    Product* p = Product::createProduct();
   
    foo(*p);            // call 1: works fine
    foo<Product>(*p);   // call 2: fails to compile
       
    Product::destroyProduct(p);
           
    return 0;
}
```

And the error message from clang:

```
error: static_assert failed due to requirement 'std::is_destructible<Product>::value' "T must be destructible"
    static_assert(std::is_destructible<T>::value, "T must be destructible");
    ^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
note: in instantiation of template class 'Bar<Product>' requested here
    foo<Product>(*p);   // call 2: fails to compile
                 ^
note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'foo' [with T = Product]
    foo<Product>(*p);   // call 2: fails to compile
    ^
1 error generated.
```

My understanding is that both `call 1` and `call 2` should compile fine, but `call 2` fails to compiler not only on clang but also on gcc and msvc.

From the standard perspective, is it correct that `call 1` succeeds and `call 2` fails to compile? Why?

**Note**: I know that I can work around the error by adding a `std::enable_if` to the first overload of `foo`, but I'd like to understand why `call 1` is OK but `call 2` is not.

Comment: `foo<Product>` (might) instantiate `Bar<Product>` which might be a match (but it is not).   But `Bar<Product>` leads to an hard error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Substitution failure is not an error is limited.  If failure occurs beyond the "immediate context", the failure is hard and not prevented by SFINAE.

When you type `foo<Product>(`?`)`, it creates an overload set first.  This overload set includes both overloads of `foo`.  But creating the first overload of foo leads to a `static_assert` failure outside of the immediate context, so a hard error.

When you type `foo(`?`)` it also tries to create an overload set.  Both of the templates are considered.  It has no `T` being passed in, so it attempts to deduce the `T` from the arguments.

The argument is a `Product&`.  Deducing `T const&` from a `Product&` produces `T=Product const`.  Deducing `Bar<T> const&` from a `Product&` ... fails to deduce a `T`, as neither `Product` nor any of its base classes are produced from a template of the form `Bar<typename>`.

Without a `T` deduced, the `foo(Bar<T> const&)` overload is discarded.  There is no way for `T=Product` to be deduced, so no hard error from attempting to instantiate `foo(Bar<Product> const&)` could occur.

In short, for call 2, you manually force a `Bar<Product>` possibility into existence.  For call 1, the compiler attempt to deduce the template arguments never gets there.

As a thought experiment, consider changing the declaration of `Product` to:

```
class Product: public Bar<int> {
```

and leave everything else the same.

Now

```
foo(*p)
```

will generate 2 overload to consider - one

```
template<class T=Product const>
void foo(Product const&)
```

and one

```
template<class T=int>
void foo(Bar<int> const&)
```

with the second one being generated by looking at the base classes of `Product` and finding a `Bar<int>`.  `T` is deduced to `Product` in one case, and `int` in the other.

But when you do `foo<Product>` you aren't relying on deduction to find `T` - you are setting it manually.  There isn't any deduction left to do.

Answer (score 2):

In `foo(*p)`, as `Product` is not a `Bar<T>`, no `void foo(Bar<T> const &)` is instantiated.

The only possible overload is `template<typename T> void foo(T const &)`.

In `foo<Product>(*p)`, you specify template parameter, so there are following candidate

- `foo<Product>(const Bar<Product>&)`
- `foo<Product>(const Product&)`

To know if `Product` can be converted to `Bar<Product>`, you have to instantiate it , producing an hard error.

Compiler might instantiate that template, even if it would not be taken by overload resolution.

foo (might) instantiate Bar which might be a match (but it is not). But Bar leads to an hard error.